# How to access IBOutlets declared in superclass?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibaction, iboutlet

I'm currently refactoring a couple of view controllers that share a few `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction` methods. I moved the outlet declarations and the `IBAction` method into a superclass, cutting these out of the subclasses.

Now, when I open up Interface Builder, I find that I can't see the outlets or actions declared in the superclass. The connections still exist, as I'd wired them up before the refactoring, but they're grayed out. (It's important to note that the connections also WORK, as my action fires on a button press, and my outlets are modified properly.)

The question is, how can I get interface builder to recognize outlets from a superclass? Is this possible, and, if not, what do you all recommend?

(Just for fun, here's my superclass header file:)

```
@interface TFMainViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *logoImage, *thinkfunImage;
    UIButton *buyFullButton;        
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage, *thinkfunImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buyFullButton;

-(IBAction) buyFullVersion;

@end
```

EDIT: in case anyone's wondering, I'm using Xcode and IB 3.2.5, with the iOS 4.2 SDK.

Comment: did you ever figure out if this is possible or not? I was hoping to do the same but IB doesn't seem to recognise the property unless I redeclared it in the subclass?

Comment: any news on this item? I'm encountering same issue here -this time with Installer Plugin superclass (InstallerPane) which isn't mine, so I can't modify it --- only documentation says I must connect my .xib to some properties of the superclass!!! How to?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I didn't realize it was even possible to connect to superclasses in interface builder until about an hour ago.  Since this was the only question I could find regarding how to do this, I'll add my answer, even though this question is old.  My answer is with regard to Xcode 4, not Xcode 3.

As far as I can tell, you can't connect to outlets in a superclass using the assistant editor, but you can do it by clicking on "File's Owner" in IB.  That should show all the outlets in Utilities->Connections Inspector.  You can then Ctrl+Click on the outlet in the inspector (click on the '+' sign), and drag it over to your view in IB.

Comment: Or just navigate with Cmd-Click to the superclass in the assistant editor, then you can drag from the class to IB or vice versa to connect outlets or create new ones.

Answer (score 18):

The solution for the problem with the IBOutlet .. is to change the class type to the Base Class in the identity inspector

[image]

connect using Control + drag and drop and

[image]

change it back to the child class

[image]

This works for me

BTW: i used Xcode 6

Comment: i have the same problem. tried that, with NSCollectionViewItem, so i can connect the textField outlet, but still its not working..

Answer (score 3):

IB should be able to see outlets from superclasses, I have done this a number of times with no issues.  Are you sure you are importing the superclass correctly (using #import instead of @class)?  IB needs some way to track back to the superclass.

Comment: Kendall, taking a look at the other answer, are you duplicating anything, or is the entire declaration in the superclass? I'm using `#import`, and do have access to the properties within the subclasses, so I know the header import's working.

Comment: I just created a test project for this - and it doesn't work. As of Xcode 7.x - IB only shows IBOutlets of the actual class declared for an object, not those of its superclasses.

Comment: I was just playing around with this in Xcode 7.3 in Swift and it still works fine.  I was able to have an IBOutlet declared in the superclass, and either drag from it into IB, or drag from IB to the outlet to connect it.  The Assistant editor does not show the superclass in the Automatic section but you can navigate there, and IB shows the outlet as coming from the subclass (which is technically accurate).  @SamRitchie - don't duplicate anything, just have the outlet in the superclass, not in the subclass.

Answer (score 3):

Switching between the super and subclass in the identity inspector allows you to connect your outlets across the classes. The only issue I found is when you attempt to do this with a UITableViewCell and its subclass. I wanted to re-assign the default textLabel and detailTextLabel instances to labels I create in Interface Builder. The workaround is to create substitute labels and then override the getters to point to these instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that IB only looks at the actual class you're using to find outlets, and not at superclasses. I think that the easiest solution would be to leave the instance variable declarations in the superclass, but duplicate the `@property` lines in each subclass.

Comment: Actually, Interface Builder *will* list properties from superclasses, but they must be declared in the header file (of the superclass only), and that header must be imported by the subclass (as Kendall said).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in XCode 3.2.6.  I started with outlets connected to a class, and then made a subclass with additional outlets.  When I changed the File's Owner class to the subclass, IB showed the superclass outlets as greyed out.  I switched File's Owner to the superclass, then back to the subclass and now all outlets are showing not greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: create interface and implementation files for your subclass(es)!
Perfect example: [Juggleware's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326398/juggleware) awesome [ShadowButton Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603733/2078664) of UIButton.

Make sure to create the .h & .m files in your project.
NOTE: There is no need to `#import` the header files at all since this is simply a *class instance* of UIButton.

In **Interface Builder**:

1. Select the element you which to connect.
2. Go to **Utilities** -> **Identity Inspector**
3. Change the Class to your subclass (or superclass).  NOTE: You might have to type in your subclass name and hit ENTER.

You're done!

Even if you have declared a basic class (UIButton) as IBOutlet in your header file like so...

```
// YourViewController.h

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *mybutton;
}
```

...the class you've set in Interface Builder (ShadowButton) will overwrite it since it's in the view layer.

The best part about this approach is that your code doesn't have any messy dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

On the project I am currently working, we have a `BaseViewController` with a `UIScrollView` as `IBOutlet` and handles keyboard appearance/disappearance events and slides the content accordingly. At first, I could not connect to that `IBOutlet`, than solved the problem like this, which is similar to Sosily's answer:

- `BaseViewController` has an `IBOutlet`, called `contentScrollView`. I can see 5 previously connected outlets, which are `UIScrollViews` on other `UIViewControllers`, created by people who previously worked on the project
- I tried to connect my `UIScrollView` as the `contentScrollView`. Although my `UIViewController` is a subclass of `BaseViewController`, I cannot connect it.
- I tried to connect already connected `UIScrollViews` as the `contentScrollView`. Although all `UIViewControllers` are subclasses of `BaseViewController`, I cannot connect them again, as well. So, I started to look for a trick.
- I have created the same `contentScrollView` `IBOutlet` on my own `UIViewController`, connected the `scrollView` to my own `contentScrollView` outlet and removed the one that I have just created.
- Now the scrollView is connected as `contentScrollView` to File's Owner, but the only `contentScrollView` belongs to the `BaseViewController`. Tested and verified that keyboard events are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a superclass, but it was due to a bug in Xcode (8.2) where Interface Builder doesn't show outlets in the Connection Inspector if those outlets have been declared with a `_Nullable` type annotation for Swift compatibility.

Using `nullable` inside @property's parentheses appears to work around the problem.

This Xcode bug seems to affect outlets in any class (ie. not just superclasses).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turns out it was because in the superclass I had the IBOutlets declared as "_Nullable".
Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)   IBOutlet UITableView *_Nullable mySuperTableView;
```

When I removed the _Nullable, suddenly the IBOutlets reappeared in IB and all was good again.
(I had only set them to _Nullable because Xcode was complaining "pointer is missing a nullability type specifier"... (don't know why). )