# iOS nib issue, causing crash

Tags: ios, xcode, nib

I have a rather peculiar error in my app

It only just started happening after it being fine for so long, all my nibs are wired up correctly from what I can see

Any other advice would be greatly appreciated

The error is as follows

2012-07-06 15:07:22.761 xxxxx[681:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MyTableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1907022 0x1b64cd6 0x1906ee1 0x11df022 0x1150f6b 0x1150edb 0x116bd50 0xa5371a 0x1908dea 0x18727f1 0xa5226e 0xa53eb7 0x830ce1 0x830ff8 0x83017f 0x83f183 0x83fc38 0x833634 0x1f4cef5 0x18db195 0x183fff2 0x183e8da 0x183dd84 0x183dc9b 0x82fc65 0x831626 0xe544 0x2255)
terminate called throwing an exception

If theres anything I can do to provide extra please let me know

Thanks all

Comment: Have you checked this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: Have you tried going to iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings? [As seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232766/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception)

Comment: @JoshGreifer I did see that thread and didnt help though

Comment: @Dima I Had'nt tried that, but did not help, the crash also happens in the the device

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have an outlet defined somewhere in your xib called 'MyTableView' and there is no property by that name.

Check all of your outlets!

Comment: Also check if you synthesized then with `@synthesize` and that the file onwer of the `xib` is set to the correct viewController.

Comment: Wonder how it was working nicely and start crashing all of sudden.

Comment: There is certainly an outlet by the name of 'MyTableView' in xib file, I @synthesize and that the file onwner is correct.

Comment: Also note that this app is falling over at the main interface xib, if I change it to another xib file which is also wired up correctly, I then get another xib related error