# Application crash after updated to IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsexception

I have updated my app to **IOS7** and now I have very strange issue.
When I start app it start to do what it suppose to do and after 3-5 minutes app stops to work.
 But not completely. It stops to send notifications, track location etc.
And if I try to make some action I get this in console:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0305f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0276e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0305f3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x0157465c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
    4   UIKit                               0x013e6c95 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    5   UIKit                               0x013e743d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    6   UIKit                               0x013e773e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x0140d1a5 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 39
    8   UIKit                               0x0140d6bb -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    9   UIKit                               0x0140d7b3 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 78
    10  UIKit                               0x0140e72c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
    11  UIKit                               0x0140f349 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    12  UIKit                               0x0154839d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    13  UIKit                               0x0cf0656f -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) layoutSubviews] + 50
    14  UIKit                               0x0133edd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0278081f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00ef972a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00eed514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00eed380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00e55156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00e564e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00f12870 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    22  UIKit                               0x012f0979 _afterCACommitHandler + 131
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0302753e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0302748f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x030053b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x03004b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0300494b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03ce89d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x03ce87fe GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x012d494b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    31  MyApp                           0x0000759d main + 141
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c53725 start + 0
    33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea what is this?
App works fine in IOS6.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769245/terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and see whether you get exception location in code or not.. And add code. Also mention whether you are using external libraries/framework you are using for notifications and tracking or not??

Comment: Post your some of code.

Comment: I have added exception breakpoint but it doesn't stop anywhere. But I think that I have found something. I think that this issue has something with autolayout. Because app crash only on the view that doesn't have autolayout checked (I manualy detect orientation instead). But still trying to find solution. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must test this on real phone just to be sure.
I have a piece of code that refreshes some labels in the view every X seconds.
It works fine until IOS7. On IOS7 app crashes after 3 minutes and I get the error from the question.
Every time I refresh labels in the view I was opened a new connection to sqlite to get data.
In IOS7 I get error so I made one instance of data access class and init it only in viewDidLoad() and now it works fine.
If after test I confirm that I am right I will definitely make singleton pattern of my data access class.

Answer (score 1):

Create an exception breakpoint in Xcode that stops on all exceptions. Then the debugger will stop when that exception is raised. It looks like it is in

```
[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
```

But I can't tell if you are calling that or the system.

See here for a related issue:
[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232766/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception)

Comment: That is called by the system. So if it was that then apple have messed up big style

Comment: `[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]` is something that can't be called by the developer. This error has nothing to do with that method, and if it did it would need reporting to apple but since it is a very important method that gets called a lot I would suspect it would already have been reported if there was anything wrong with it.

Comment: I am not saying that that method is being called by the developer. That method is merely the one throwing the exception, as you can see in the trace. Probably implemented very well by Apple, to warn the developer about something the developer did, like specifying a wrong owner, or no owner maybe. System method can raise exceptions, and for that, they do not need to be called by the developer, however the trigger for the exception can be in developer-code. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232766/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception

Comment: This happens only on one view. I have checked all IBOutlets all is fine :(

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint as I suggested? Then the debugger will stop when the exception is thrown and you can work your way back.

Comment: Yes but it stops in int main(). That is wired there are no exception in my code. It simply on that view stop receive notifications etc. If I use another view it works fine. But can't figure what can make this.

Comment: No, it does not happen in main(). That is where the debugger stops if the exception is not caught. In your trace you see that there is an exception. Create an Exception Breakpoint, run your app and recreate the problem, then debugger won't stop in main() but closer to the actual problem.

Comment: Ughh... I have tried the same now and figure one thing that could actually break my app. After 3 minutes from some reason I can't access to local sqlite. View still receives notifications but can't access database thats why I get zeros after 3 min. And when I try to open another view that require database access my app crash. Hmmm...