# iOS: include a xib into another xib?

Tags: ios, xib

How to include a xib into another xib?

For example Android:
[Android: include a xml into an other xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306791/android-include-a-xml-into-an-other-xml)

It looks useful for common UI.
I am trying to search but I am not able to do this, can sameone help me?

Comment: Sure, go here .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723332/294884

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: This is not supported.

While they look like XML files, they are not read as "normal" XML files like they are on Android systems. Instead, they're "property lists", or plists, and use only a small subset of XML. And there's nothing in Apple's code, AFAIK, that would interpret any additional XML schemes and other tags that would support inclusion of other files.