# Add background shadow to UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

How can add a light gray shadow to a `UIButton`, I don't want a method to do this at the moment, it should be something like:

```
UIButton *button1... button1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
```

etc, but that doesn't work, it only adds a shadow inside the button, but I need it on the outside. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315366/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-a-uibutton

Comment: I saw that already, but I don't want methods. Also I'm adding a button to a table cell if that helps.

Comment: please check the answer given by "fzwo". That is not a method.

Comment: I tried that, I even created a button object and replaced self with the button name, but still not working.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I couldn't see the shadow with a shadow radius of 12, after refusing it to 3 I got it I think. Thanks!

Comment: yes, but I did it a different way

Answer (score 11):

First you have to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. Then:

```
mybtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
mybtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
mybtn.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
mybtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.0f,3.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`–[UIButton setBackgroundImage:forState:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a) to set the background image for [`UIControlStateNormal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlStateNormal) to one with a shadow. E.g.:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBackgroundNormal"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where `ButtonBackgroundNormal.png` has a shadow. Images often render faster than drawing with code. And, speed is important, especially if you're adding it to a `UITableViewCell`. In that case, to speed up scrolling speed, make sure the background image is completely opaque by designing it with the same background color of the `UITableViewCell` and saving it without transparency. Then, set `button.opaque = YES`.