# how to add shadow to a custom category class in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am creating a custom catagory class for UIButton but it doesn't have the shadow functionality in it. So how should I add shadow on the button when that button is clicked.

Comment: Do you mean an effect when the user taps or the shadow should be permanent ?

Comment: yes i mean an effect when the user taps that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need highlight on your button than just add:

```
button.highlighted= YES;
```

and if you want shadow of hover type effect than just add another image to ur button and set it controlstatenormal to hightlighted that is :

```
//for normal tap
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//for hovering effect
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: button.highlighted sets it to higlighted state from the very beginning, but I just wanted to know that if there is any inbuilt property of UIButton by which we can add shadow to the custom button without relying on the background images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169225/add-background-shadow-to-uibutton may this link help u

Answer (score 0):

Every button has few states :

```
  enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
  };
```

You can set a different image for each state with:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

If you want to set only the title shadow, you can use:

```
- (void)setTitleShadowColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
```

**BTW**

If you are using IB you can set the state images in the interface.

Comment: I tried to change the title shadow color but there was no change in the shadow effect of the UIButton...  I want the shadow to be all over the button.

Comment: I you want to change under all the button you should set a different image to the highlighted state. and then set the button state to highlighted. see @Aaaaa answer