# Setting layer out of layer in UIbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, calayer

[image]

i want this type of button 
i have tried pictureBtn which is `UIbutton` ,i gave it a 5 pixel clear color corner radius and add a picture like camera below but last outer white line how to deal with this can anybody have ideas or something like control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315366/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-a-uibutton   may this help u

Comment: dude i tried this before didn't work for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my output code for my solution -

```
    UIButton *picBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];

    [picBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CM.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [picBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [picBtn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];

    [picBtn.layer setCornerRadius:picBtn.frame.size.height/2];

    [picBtn.layer setBorderWidth:2];

    [picBtn.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: @Yagnesh gave me hint for this

Comment: Welcome @Ghanshyam Tomar.    or u can also design an image with outer border and set that image as a background image.....!!! –

Answer (score 1):

For this design put button in one view and set 5 pixel gap between view and button.
Than set 2 pixel border of view.

Comment: Yes that was i thought(noobs thought this one too) but i want to use only one control i know this is done by the help of shadow or something in UIButton but don't know how. anyway thx for answer

Comment: That i don't know, If you know in feature than say me. Thanx in advance, and Welcome .

Comment: Ok Beautiful coder i will surely reply you if i found.

Answer (score 1):

set image through attribute setImage rather then  setBackgroundImage,
do UIButton backgroungColor clear color,
and set border for UIButton

Comment: hey dude you have the point you gave me clue i use same and use EdgeInsets for the clear space.+1 vote

Comment: or u can also design an image with outer border and set that image as a background image.....!!!

Comment: Yes our designer also said that but i want to create my-self i and i did it tnx for help.