# UIButton bottom shadow with radius and gradient

Tags: objective-c

How can I do this behaviour using Objective-C code and not using an image for the drop shadow of this button?

If you look closely you will se that the shadow hasn't the same colour on everywhere , it seems that the black it's more intense near the button and lose alpha as it goes away.

Is there a way? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
self.yourBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 18; // (Height of your Btn /2)
self.yourBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.yourBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
self.yourBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
self.yourBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,6.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's partially doing the trick but I try to go closer to the design.

Comment: Try with my update ans. I have changed some values.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Link

[Shadow Of UIButton_Help Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315366/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-a-uibutton)

Or

[Shadow Of UIButton_Help Link 2](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-shadow-to-a-button)